# Multiple condition in a single SUMIF function

Tags: mysql

`SELECT 
     IFNULL(SUM(IF(A=1 and B=2, 'Correct', NULL)),0)
 FROM
     table`

Please I am using such function above in my query. Although it works but i want to Know if this is the right way of handling multiple conditions within one single query in mysql. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No.  This is not correct.  You cannot sum a string value.  MySQL will convert it to a number.  Because `'Correct'` it starts with a letter, your query will always return 0.

I think you intend:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(A=1 and B=2, 1, 0)) as Correct
FROM table
```

Note that this gets rid of the outer `ifnull()`.  I would also suggest using `COALESCE()` rather than `IF()` because it is ANSI standard functionality.  However, this conditional is not needed.

The query can be further simplified.  In fact, the best way to write this query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE A = 1 and B = 2;
```

In general, it is better to write queries with the conditions in the `WHERE` clause rather than in conditional statements (if possible).  This reduces the number of rows that the rest of the query needs to process.